# kotlin lazy toString

Tags: kotlin, lazy-evaluation, tostring, delegation

Let's say I have a `toString` method that takes a long time to return a result but its value won't change once it's computed.
The best we have come up with is this (thanks @Tenfour04 for the comment):

```
class MyClass {
    private val _toString: String by lazy {
        /** something that takes a while to compute**/
    }
    override fun toString() = _toString
}
```

but it's not perfect because the class still has to implement an extra `_toString` property.

Ideally I am looking for some sort of delegation of the method, like I did for the property... but I can't create an interface with `toString` and delegate its implementation because it's a method of `Any`.

Comment: You can't delegate functions the way you can properties, but you could use your last code block in combination with `override fun toString() = _toString` to make it a little shorter.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Yeah I thought about that too but that still adds an additional a private variable in the class which I hoped I could avoid.

Comment: I think you cannot get around using an extra variable. Or at least I'm not aware of any mechanism.